# Directive with two template containers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a "version" directive:

```js
$scope.text = "Lorem ipsum";
$scope.target = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

```html
<table>
    <version array="target">
        <one>
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="col">ONE {{version}}: {{ text }}</td>
            </tr>
        </one>
        <many>
            <tr class="row" ng-repeat="version in versions">
                <td class="col">MANY {{version}}: {{ text }}</td>
            </tr>
        </many>
    </version>
</table>
```

It acts pretty simple, it just substitutes one of the templates defined within `one` or `many` elements depending on the amount of elements fed to it. In our case it's called `target`. In case when array contains one element, directive uses template defined within `one` element, if more that it uses template defined in `many` element. Directive is also restricted to not producing redundant html elements, so that we don't end up with some strange divs inside table.

[HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/0ckbz2n7/50/](http://jsfiddle.net/0ckbz2n7/50/) (Does not support switching between `one` and `many`)

I have killed all day but reached some progress with this task, as you can see from `jsFiddle` url this is version #50 already and it's not the first fiddle that I'm trying to create from scratch, other than that I feel like I'm doing it wrong way, so maybe you guys who have more experience than I do can help me with finishing this task cuz I see no light in the end of the chamber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code quite a bit. Is this what you want?

```
app.directive('version', function($compile) {
      var oneTemplate = '';
      var twoTemplate = '';
      return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watchCollection($attrs['track'], function(newVal, oldVal) {
                     var template;
                     $element.empty();
                     delete $scope.versions;
                     delete $scope.version;
                     if (newVal) {
                        if(newVal.length === 1) {
                            $scope.version = newVal[0];
                            template = angular.element(oneTemplate);
                        } else {
                            $scope.versions = newVal;
                            template = angular.element(twoTemplate)
                        }
                        $element.append(template);
                        $compile(template)($scope);
                     }
                });
            },
            compile: function(element, attr) {
                oneTemplate = element.find('one').html();
                twoTemplate = element.find('many').html();
            }
      };
  })
```

EDIT:

It should be $watchCollection instead of $watch, since you are watching an array.

Additionally if you don't want to create a directive, you could simply use ng-switch:

```
<div class="table" ng-switch="target.length" ng-init="version = target[0]; versions = target">
    <div class="row" ng-switch-when="1">
        <div class="col">ONE {{version}}: {{ text }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-switch-default="" ng-repeat="version in target">
        <div class="col">MANY {{version}}: {{ text }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ckbz2n7/60/

Comment: Currently learning your code, it's definitely way better than my, however if you click "click me" button twice, you won't get `one` template rendered...

Comment: Yeah, you need to use $watchCollection instead of $watch

Comment: Oh, didn't knew such function exists, man you've saved me another day, thank you!